# multiple request from same ip on Server logs

Tags: apache, logging

I implemented a client side interface which makes a service call to the server using JS in an http GET. When checking my access logs, I see that sometimes, I get multiple requests sometimes as many as 6 within a second-- Making the very same request-- from the same ip -- what do u think this tells ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It might tell they're behind a proxy. (the IP you see is actually the proxy's IP)

Answer (score 1):

It could be 6 different computers behind one router, all visiting your page. Or 6 tabs on one browser of one computer. Or a bug in your JavaScript?